# Conditionally set task input based on runtime values

Tags: azure-pipelines

after reading the Conditions and Expressions documentation for Pipelines, it doesn't seem like this is possible, but maybe someone has come up with a workaround. I'd like to conditionally set a tasks' input based on the success/failure of a previous step. I've tried to following ways but no luck.

NOTE: the following is a minimal example, and bash task is not really ideal but demonstrates the point. The actual task I'm trying to use is one that has an input variable to publish test results, but that should only be 'True' if a connection to the test archive (a previous task) was successful.

```yaml
# Ideal as the condition is right in the input parameter
steps:
- checkout: none
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'echo "the result was $[succeeded()]"'
```

```yaml
# Would be acceptable, but I can't find how to reference a previous step, unlike a job/stage with dependencies
steps:
- checkout: none
- script: echo Hello, world!
  name: say_hello
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- task: Bash@3
  condition: eq(succeeded(), ??reference to success of say_hello step??)'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: "Excellent!"

- task: Bash@3
  condition: eq(failed(), ??reference to success of say_hello step??)'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: "Oh no it failed!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the below solution may work for your requirement. I conditionally execute a task based on a variable that is generated on runtime.

```
trigger:
- none

variables:

- name: var1
  value: value1

- name: var2
  value: value2

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
jobs:
  - job: job1
    displayName: job1

    steps:

    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: task1
      name: task1
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host running task1
          Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=outputvar;isOutput=true]kati"

  - job: job2
    dependsOn: job1
    displayName: job2
    variables:
      myvar: $[ dependencies.job1.outputs['task1.outputvar'] ]
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: run if task1 has run successfully
      name: task2
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.myvar, 'kati'))
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host running task2
```

If the variable is not something, then the task will not run.

[image]

If the exported variable is the requested then the task will run.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @GeralexGR, however this is between jobs, which you can do directly using dependencies with `eq(dependencies.<depName>.result, 'Succeeded')`. While I could refactor, the ideal answer to the question is to do it within the same job

Comment: @errorline1 I think the approach of using an [output variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks) is the best way for you, even if the tasks are within the same job.

Comment: Okay yep I can see in that article how it could be done, but I still don't know how I could reference the success/fail of a previous task. In the example, we're directly using cmdline to create the output variable, but how would we do that for a task? The task I'm dealing with is [SonarQubePrepare](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-vsts/blob/master/extensions/sonarqube/tasks/prepare/v5/task.json), which doesn't list any outputs, and if I try to do `echo $(say_hello)` (from docs), I get `say_hello: command not found`. Is the only way to not use a task and write each line?